# How to join these two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

**Table "one":**

```
ServiceID, ApplicationCode, Success
1, 1, 2
1, 3, 2
2, NULL, 3
```

**Table "two":**

```
ServiceID, ApplicationCode, Failure
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 3
2, NULL, 4
3, NULL, 1
```

I want to receive that **result table**:

***Columns:***

```
ServiceID, ApplicationCode, Success, Failure
1, 1, 2, 1
1, 3, 2, NULL
2, NULL, 3, 4
1, 2, NULL, 3
3, NULL, NULL, 1
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

What query should I use ?

**EDITED: I'm looking to join the two tables by ServiceID and ApplicationCode.**

**EDITED 2:** 
Code I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO #MidResult(ServiceID,ApplicationCode,SuccessCount,FailureCount)
SELECT case rtrim(ltrim(s.ServiceID)) WHEN NULL THEN f.ServiceID ELSE s.ServiceID END,s.ApplicationCode,s.SuccessCount,f.FailureCount
FROM #SuccessResult s
FULL JOIN #FailureResult f on f.ApplicationCode = s.ApplicationCode and s.ServiceID = f.ServiceID
```

Comment: I have tried joining the two tables, but I'm always missing some row from one table or another

Comment: On SO, when you are asked what you have tried, that means that you should show the code you have so far and the concrete problems with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use the following:

```
select 
  coalesce(t1.serviceid, t2.serviceid) serviceid,
  coalesce(t1.ApplicationCode, t2.ApplicationCode) ApplicationCode,
  t1.Success,
  t2.failure
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2
  on t1.ServiceID = t2.ServiceID
  and isnull(t1.ApplicationCode, '') = isnull(t2.ApplicationCode, '')
order by serviceid, ApplicationCode
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92355/5).

The result is:

```
| SERVICEID | APPLICATIONCODE | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
---------------------------------------------------
|         1 |               1 |       2 |       1 |
|         1 |               2 |  (null) |       3 |
|         1 |               3 |       2 |  (null) |
|         2 |          (null) |       3 |       4 |
|         3 |          (null) |  (null) |       1 |
```

Comment: The "2, NULL" row should become into one: "2, null, 3, 4"

Answer (score -1):

```
Select one.ServiceID, one.ApplicationCode, one.Success, two.Failure
From TableOne one , TableTwo two
where one.ServiceID = two.ServiceID
and one.ApplicationCode = two.ApplicationCode
```

just notice that both ServiceID and ApplicationCode should match.

Comment: Sometimes ApplicationCode doesn't exist in the other table, so the row will be missing in the result table

Comment: Then how do you want to join them? You can't rely on ServiceID because it is duplicated. And you said "EDITED: I'm looking to join the two tables by ServiceID **AND** ApplicationCode." so why downvote?